# VPN daisy-chaining via Virtual Machines

Tags: vpn

Assume that my host is a Windows computer. I have Virtualbox installed and I put on it another Windows guest.

Assuming I connect with my host to a VPN provider called "A" with OpenVPN and with my guest I also connect to a different VPN provider called "B" and navigate on the internet through my guest on VPN B, would I effectively be "doubly " protected?

Can somebody explain to me how would this work exactly?

Would "VPN-inception" add 1 degree of protection every time one does it? (e.g, a virtual machine in a virtual machine in a virtual machine with each virtual machine having each a VPN connection to a different provider).

Comment: Please add more details explaining who is connecting where. The N in VPN stands for network, so somewhere there has to be a network, preferably with DHCP server, gateway, etc. Where is that place?

Comment: I have tried rewording the question. All networking services are provided by the VPN client (OpenVPN). You just connect to your provider.

Comment: How would that work if they're all coming off the same host which is the source?